# handling $1 in shell script directory path

Tags: bash, shell-script, arguments, cwd

I have this part of the script(bash) that worked absolutely fine until recently but it throws me an error with file not found when using $1 to give directory path. Only difference I know is it stopped working after we upgraded to rhel 7.

here is the part of the script:

```
MOUNTINST=/opt/mqm80_Inst1

$1/crtMQdir.ksh $MOUNTINST/bin 755 mqm
$1/crtMQdir.ksh $MOUNTINST/logs 755 mqm
$1/crtMQdir.ksh $MOUNTINST/java/lib/soap 755 mqm
```

I am in the right directory path and also made sure the file exists:

```
   /var/mqm/trace/WMQUNX8000.02]
    $ ll *crt*
    -rwxr-xr-x. 1 mqm mqm 826 Apr 10  2014 crtMQdir.ksh
```

Here is the error I get:

```
./test5.sh: line 4: /crtMQdir.ksh: No such file or directory
./test5.sh: line 6: /crtMQdir.ksh: No such file or directory
./test5.sh: line 8: /crtMQdir.ksh: No such file or directory
```

Am I missing something ?

Comment: What command did you run that resulted in those errors?

Comment: ./test5.sh under /var/mqm/trace/WMQUNX8000.02

Contents of test5.sh are 

`MOUNTINST=/opt/mqm80_Inst1

$1/crtMQdir.ksh $MOUNTINST/bin 755 mqm
$1/crtMQdir.ksh $MOUNTINST/logs 755 mqm
$1/crtMQdir.ksh $MOUNTINST/java/lib/soap 755 mqm`

Comment: You have to give directory path as an argument of `test5.sh` where those `.ksh` files are exists 

For example: 
    ./test5.sh /home/abcd/bin

Comment: I was thinking $1/crtMQdir.ksh will lead to /var/mqm/trace/WMQUNX8000.02/crtMQdir.ksh since $1 implies PWD. Am I wrong?

Comment: You are, `$1` is the first parameter, not the PWD.

Comment: `$1` inside the `BASH` script means the first argument to the script

Comment: A quick `echo` in front of the offending line would have immediately told you what's trying to be done.

Comment: Running the script with `set -x` at the top would also have shown you exactly what commands gets executed.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to give the path as an argument for the script, as `$1` is the first argument of the script.

If you want the path and the script name (complete path of the script, e.g `/path/to/crtMQdir.ksh`), you need to use `$0` instead.

You also need to ensure that your `ksh` script has execution permissions: `chmod +x /path/to/crtMQdir.ksh`

An alternate way, if you want to run it from the current directory, is to simply replace `$1` by `$PWD` in your current script.  If you want it to use the same directory as the one to this script, you could also use `$(dirname $0)` instead of the `$1`.